# How to overcome from this issue in jquery for an animated hover effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tooltip, jquery-hover

In the following link there is an example for an [animated hover effect](http://www.webdesignerwall.com/demo/jquery/animated-hover1.html) . If we hover the mouse in a particular list the tool-tip will appear and disappear, here no problem. If we continuosly move the mouse up & down in a particular list the tool-tip appear for several times (for example if we move the mouse for ten times the tool-tip also appear for ten times).

How to overcome from this issue (i.e) if we hover the particular list for several time,the tool-tip should appear only once.

I tried it by changing the script as (by adding stop() function)

```
    $(".menu a").hover(function() {
    $(this).next("em").stop().animate({opacity: "show", top: "-75"}, "slow");
```

but it's failed....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `.stop(true, true)` to stop the animation. ***[Check the working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZYLzs/)***.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".menu a").hover(function() {
        $(this).next("em").stop(true, true).animate({opacity: "show", top: "-75"}, "slow");
    }, function() {
        $(this).next("em").stop(true, true).animate({opacity: "hide", top: "-85"}, "fast");
    });
});
```

***Explaination:***

`.stop(true, true)` will remove the queued animation and complete the current animation immediately.

> ```
> .stop( [clearQueue] [, jumpToEnd] )
> ```
>
> **clearQueueA** Boolean indicating whether to remove queued animation as
>   well. Defaults to false.
>
> **jumpToEndA** Boolean indicating whether to complete the current
>   animation immediately. Defaults to false.

Comment: can u explain me what the function (i.e)".stop(true,true)" did in this script?

Answer (score 0):

Use $(".menu li").hover for the tool-tip to appear once.

Comment: you are attaching hover event to a. when you try to move the mouse continuously up, it means you are not hovering on the "a". That's y the tooltip gets disappear. If you attach event to li, as tooltip is part of li, tooltip does not disppear when you move mouse up over the tooltip .

Answer (score 0):

You can specify only a hover event, and that will fire whenever there is a `mouseenter`, you cannot specify something like "This hover should fire only if the previous hover fired at east 5 seconds earlier". You can use the [Hoverintent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) plugin to specify that the hover should fire only when the mouse has been inside for say 0.5 seconds.